# How to tell when a vim script is being sourced

Tags: vim

How can I tell if my script is being sourced on or after startup?

For example, I want to write a function that responds to the ttymouse setting, say CheckMouseSetting(). This setting, however, is oddly enough loaded after startup scripts are loaded -- I'm not sure why. I could use a VimEnter autocommand, but this won't activate if the user is simply sourcing this file after startup. I could have both, ie:

```
call CheckMouseSetting()
au * VimEnter call CheckMouseSetting()
```

But this is not ideal as it may produce unwanted error messages -- so, hence my question.

Comment: Did you read `:help startup`?

Answer (score 0):

Clarification:  you want the function to know whether it is being sourced at startup or later, right?

I think you have a little blind spot:  the simplest solution is to tell the function:

```
:call CheckMouseSetting('myscript')
:au * VimEnter call CheckMouseSetting('VimEnter')
```

In response you your comment:  if you want to tell when the file is sourced (during startup or interactively) then you can add a script-local variable:

```
:let s:source_count = exists('s:source_count') ? s:source_count + 1 : 1
:call CheckMouseSetting('myscript', s:source_count)
```

If you really want a more "automatic" way to tell, then @romainl's comment is on target.  (I think there was a time when I was the only one besides Bram who had ever read that section of the help.)

Comment: Hmm, yes, that would work to distinguish between a VimEnter autocommand and a (source at or source after startup) but not between a startup source or a file source.

Lol I had actually skimmed through :h startartup to see if I can detect anything -- anything! -- in the environment. I noticed that shelloptions is set after vimrc is sourced, but it is not empty, so I can't use that.

Comment: Clarification: I need to differentiate between the *first time* that someone sources a script interactively and the startup. Doing a 'soruce_count' won't work in that case. Ie, I'm not assuming that they have sourced the script on startup, so interactvely would not always be the second time.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this with a guard variable, like the multiple inclusion guard at the start of plugin files.

```
function! myplugin#CheckMouseSetting()
    if exists('s:hasBeenChecked')
        return
    endif
    let s:hasBeenChecked = 1
    ...
```

If you define this function in an *autoload* script, you can invoke it from the `VimEnter` event, and alternatively instruct users who want to have this manually to `call` the function, which is easier than `:source` / `:runtime`, because it avoids the path issues.

Comment: Hmm... you are providing workarounds, and there are a few. Instructing the user is one. I can simply print an error message that says "oh, an btw, and if you see me during startup, ignore me". I do admit that the original problem is one of those FTNPI problems (fairly trivial and not particularly intereseting). Sort of like how the whole nature nurture debate is FINPE (fairly intractable and not particularly enlgihtening).